# Override forms in django allauth

Tags: django-forms, overriding, django-authentication, django-allauth

I'm building a project in Django, and I'm using django-allauth for the social authentication, but I had already set up an authentication system of my own.
Now, as I said, I just wanted to use django-allauth for the social authentication, but NOT for the classic authentication, since - I have tried it - it's authentication system collides with my own.

I've tried overriding the form by creating a FormView like the following:

```
class LoginUser(FormView):
    template_name = 'account/login.html'
    form_class = MyLoginForm
```

That calls this form:

```
class MyLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that login a user.
    """

    email = forms.EmailField(label='', required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'DIOCAAAAA',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'login-email'
        }
    ))

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'Password',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'login-password',
            'data-parsley-trigger': 'focusout'
        }
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)
```

And I've added this in the urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    **url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.LoginUser.as_view()),**
    [...]
)
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError at /accounts/login/
>   **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

Am I proceeding in the right direction, or should I try something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Url to be different location,I think your url conflict with allauth url,because allauth has already had this

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$')
```